# How can I soak cake in cheese?

Tags: baking, cake, cheesecake, soaking

I can make cheesecake and I can make cake, but it occurred to me recently that cheesecake isn't cake soaked in cheese, Ala tres leches.

So, is it possible to get cheese liquefied enough to be able to soak into a sponge cake?

My initial thought was to mix mascarpone with cream/condensed milk and bathe a vanilla sponge in it.

This could then be topped with meringue and pretty much any fruit.

But would that work or is even mascarpone just too thick so be absorbed?

Comment: You'd almost have better luck with 'cheese powder' (what they use on snack foods).  Or maybe even nutritional yeast instead of actual cheese.  But it'd be *much* easier to make a cream cheese frosting or filling.

Comment: Cake and bread are mostly closed cell foams. You'd have to break open the bubbles to get cheese in there. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foam#Liquid_foams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is mascarpone doesn't really have much flavour. If you dilute it and a little soaks in, you won't be able to taste it at all. The much runnier liquid used in lemon drizzle cake doesn't soak in very far. Maybe you don't want too much cheese flavour, but something like mascarpone or ricotta would be better as a filling or topping than trying to flavour the cake itself

For a real cheese flavour I reckon you'd be better off mixing cheese in before baking. I have tasted a dark chocolate and blue cheese cake. Delicious and very rich. The concept came from [Heston Blumenthal](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=_9Fi8ylaL4I).